# How to modify the cost function of Neural Network in python

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, autoencoder, loss-function

I need to make my own cost function for a neural network in Python using the packages and libraries. For instance, I want to make a cost function that is a function of the output of one of the hidden layers.

Keras and MLP from scikit-learn does not allow that. Any better package?

In Keras, you can only have a modified cost function when it is a function of predicted y and actual y. I need more flexibilty.

Comment: I don't think many people have considered doing that, so I doubt any major framework would have this feature. However, you could try writing your own network from scratch with numpy if it is simple enough. Tensorflow might allow you to go deep enough to do something like that, but not necessarily.

Comment: I think @DarthCadeus is correct. Specially because the backpropagation algorithm would have some significant changes to be implemented for such an error function. You might have to code it from scratch and moreover workout the math behind the backpropagation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an auxiliry output, for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(...)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(..)(inp)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(...)(x1)

model = tf.keras.Model(inp, [x1, x2])

model.compile(loss=['loss_for_x1', 'loss_for_x2'], 
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss_weights=[1., 1.]) # How many the loss function influences
```

You can thing of this as applying a loss directly to first layer.